# Why does T-SQL not stop on errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I do the following query

```
EXEC spFoo
PRINT 'TEST'
```

and `spFoo` throws an error, it still executes the print statement.

However if I do

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC cdb.spFoo
    PRINT 'TEST'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

It behaves as I expected and does not continue after an error.

Could someone please explain this behaviour for me? It still continues on even if I encapsulate it in a transaction. It is not just the with a print-statement but also with any other thing. My initial thought was that it was a severity problem but the severity was level 16. Is this normal T-SQL behaviour? If so, what motivates this design that contradicts every other language I have ever worked with that directly escalates the error?

I have tried and seen the same behaviour in SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2017 across several different machines. The stored procedure in question is linked to a SQL CLR.

Comment: SQL Server error mechanics aren't equal to object oriented programming languages, the error won't (always) bubble up until a catch finally handles it. For example, if the error severity is 20 or higher the session will be instantly terminated, even with a CATCH. You should try reading about transactions (and xact_abort) and common error severity levels (foreign key fails, tempdb full fail, etc.). Each error might behave differently unfortunately.

Comment: So, you've never encountered, say, Visual Basic's infamous [On Error Resume Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement) or any C-style language with an API with out-of-band error signalling (`GetLastError`-style). Your unfamiliarity with how some older languages dealt with errors doesn't make T-SQL unique in this regard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best practice use of SQL Server T-SQL error handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725891/what-is-the-best-practice-use-of-sql-server-t-sql-error-handling) pretty old question, but the link provided in the answer is very detailed: http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html

Comment: A more up to date link provided in the comments of the above answer: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Comment: and also: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would think error handling was straightforward. Not really.
I have taken a screenshot from [Erland Sommarskog's excellent article](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html), which shows how different errors behave:

[image: Error abortion and rollback matrix]

Seeing that `PRINT 'TEST'` is being ran after the failed exec, I guess you are in the Name=Statement-terminating, XACT_ABORT OFF, TRY-CATCH OFF cell which indicates "Aborts statement", which means the next statement still runs. Catching works and skips the next step.

Answer (score 3):

Severity was level 16 is a warning-level. The user is required to handle any errors - including defining when termination is required.

With your first example:

```
EXEC spFoo
PRINT 'TEST'
```

*these are independent statements* and, although `spFoo` may fail, the server will move onto the next statement. This is because severity is less than 20, the batch has not automatically been terminated.

With your second example,

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC cdb.spFoo
    PRINT 'TEST'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

*you have taken ownership of deciding what is associated with what*.

Since one item in the `TRY` block failed, it would not move onto the next.

*`THROW` always terminates a batch*.

Once you called `THROW`, if you have any code that continues afterwards, it will not be carried out. If that's important, you can use `RAISERROR` to continue.

[A detailed explanation of errors](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

[Part 2 of explanations](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html)

[An answer from the same person](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eba1b677-123a-470a-95f2-f11bf4cb3b90/raiserror-behavior-in-trycatch-block?forum=transactsql)

[Severity levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You should explanation given here for [TRY...CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> A TRY…CATCH construct catches all execution errors that have a
>   severity higher than 10 that do not close the database connection.

In SQL, TRY..CATCH  works very differently than C#/VB etc. so based on severity it works.

If you need to see if any error occurred in previous statement, use [@@ERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Example, `IF @@ERROR <> 0 PRINT 'TEST'`

Try printing what result @@ERROR giving. It may give you any hint.

Returns 0 if the previous Transact-SQL statement encountered no errors.

> (From above link) @@ERROR Returns an error number if the previous statement encountered an
>   error. If the error was one of the errors in the sys.messages catalog
>   view, then @@ERROR contains the value from the sys.messages.message_id
>   column for that error. You can view the text associated with an
>   @@ERROR error number in sys.messages.

Check if any helpful information found from @@ERROR

Comment: this don't seems like answer to the question.

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan, It depends. It is not going in Catch because of low severity and continues execution.

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan, I guess i will need to delete this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> TRY.. CATCH

Will not stop the process of the query. If you do not want to continue after catching the error, then please use `RETURN`. This will stop the process. Also if you are using `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, please use `ROLLBACK` before returning from the process. Otherwise it will end up in uncommitted transactions.